# will_paginate (getting undefined method error for boards)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Maybe this is a newbie issue but I just can't figure out was going on 
Getting an error when I refresh local host

undefined local variable or method `boards' for #<#:0x3c8eff8>
Extracted source (around line #14):

Here is the code in my index.html.erb for boards

## Listing boards

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>About</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <%= will_paginate(boards) %>
    <% @boards.each do |board| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= board.name %></td>
        <td><%= board.about %></td>
        <td><%= board.user.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', board %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_board_path(board) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', board, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Board', new_board_path %>
```

****Here is the code for my index method in board controller****

```
def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @boards = current_user.boards
    else 
      @boards = Board.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
    end

  end
```

I have added the will_paginate to my gem file

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'will_paginate'

Comment: Change it to `<%= will_paginate(@boards) %>` ?

Comment: I tried that no luck.

Comment: oh fyi im using rails v 4.1.6

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra I changed it to "@boards" but then I got another error: undefined method `total_pages' for #<Board::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x3c872a0>

Comment: Is this happening when `user_signed_in` is true?  You need to add the pagination to your first conditional assignment, i.e. `if user_signed_in? @boards = current_user.boards.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)`